# In Java make random 3byte String

Tags: java, random

How do I generate a random 3byte string in Java?

Below is the code I've written in python:

```
import random

def random_unicode(length):
    random_unicodes = [chr(random.randrange(0x999D)) for _ in range(0, length)] 
    return u"".join(random_unicodes)
```

I am trying to implement this code in Java.

Comment: post the Java code you tried

Comment: byte? you mean chars? objects in java take more than three bytes

Comment: That isn't really 3 bytes. byte -> 8 bits -> 0-256. (according to python java has a signed byte).

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error with the UTF-16. I updated the answer to correct it.

Answer (score -1):

Quite easily you can do three letters with three line

```
byte[] array = new byte[3];
new Random().nextBytes(array);
String generatedString = new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

The printed result, depending on the result Random, may look something like

> a$c

obviously changing the charset it may change the number of bytes you need to generate

```
byte[] array = new byte[6];
new Random().nextBytes(array);
String generatedString = new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
```

the he printed result may look something like

> 퓮콙噹

Comment: Why `UTF-16` ? Chances are high tht 2 consecutive random bytes do not match a valid UTF-16 character IMHO.

Comment: @Benoit Not to mention you have three bytes so that's never going to work with `UTF-16`. Probably better to use `CP-1252` and handle control characters and undefined characters.